# Cartesian product of infinite amount of finite sets bijects to?

Tags: calculus

I have an infinite amount of sets containing two values each.
$A_1 = \{a_1,_1; a_1,_2\}$ ... $A_n = \{a_n,_1; a_n,_2\}$ and so on

If a make a Cartesian product of all these sets $A_1 \times A_2 \times \ldots \times A_n \times \ldots$, 
will the product be a bijection to, or in other words, will the cardinality be equal to that of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ or real numbers $\mathbb{R}$?

 Sorry if my question is confusing due to wrong terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For concreteness, and without loss of generality,
 let's assume $A_1=A_2=\dots=A_n=\dots$, and label your two elements $0$ and $1$.

What can you say about the set $\prod_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, say compared to $[0,1)$? (E.g., thinking about binary expansion.)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can use cantor's diagonal argument to create one variation of a set (<- once again sorry if I'm not expressing myself correctly) that will be different from all others?

Comment: You don't need to recreate the argument: you can directly inject $[0,1)$ into $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ by writing $r\in[0,1)$ in base 2.

Comment: what does $r$ stand for? There's no such generalization in my language

Comment: Take any element $r\in[0,1)$, and write it in base 2. $r$ is just a name I gave to an element of $[0,1)$, I could have written $x$.